# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method (using jQuery based Slider)

Tags: jquery

On the following [**site**](http://sh.betaforming.com/), the content slider is not working.  I've used this [**content slider**](http://slidesjs.com/) on many other sites.  This site is using Twitter Bootstrap (which I'm not familiar with).

The Console error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slides'
```

I'm a JavaScript novice, so I'm not sure what to look for.  I understand what the error is saying, but I don't understand why I'm getting it on this site and not others or where to start looking.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the slide.js has loaded? Have you checked everything with Firebug or some other web developer tool?

Comment: Your website is trying to use bootstrap but all the includes fail and do not get loaded. Maybe this is causing your error because the content slider libary is successfully loaded. but you are loading jquery version 1.5.2 and 1.7.2

Comment: Did you see all the bootstrap scripts in the console that did'nt load, and jQuery loaded twice will give all sorts of problems?

Comment: You are loading 2 versions of jQuery. `http://sh.betaforming.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2` and `http://sh.betaforming.com/wp-content/themes/solutions/js/jquery.js`.  Try removing the 2nd jQuery (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: @Rocket I've already tried that, but he has to have another issue, because it didn't solve the problem. Stoked to see the right answer :-D

Comment: Wait.  I just took another look.  You are loading jQuery 3 times!  Don't do that. `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js`, `http://sh.betaforming.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2`, and `http://sh.betaforming.com/wp-content/themes/solutions/js/jquery.js`.

Comment: @EvilP: You sure?  `$.fn.jquery` says `1.7.1` (the last jQuery loaded).  The plugin is being removed when the 2nd (and 3rd) jQueries are loaded

Comment: Everything is working now, removed all the extra jQuery calls.  I forgot about the items in the footer.  Not sure why some of them weren't loading, but they aren't being used so I removed them.  I have some CSS issues to fix now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are loading jQuery 3 times.  The 1st time, you are loading it, and then loading the slides plugin.

The 2nd time you are loading jQuery, it replaces the 1st one, and all plugins.

You only need to load jQuery once at the top of the page.

Comment: Yes, that fixed everything. Thanks.  First time working with someone using Bootstrap.  Not sure I like it.